# Can I output multi-dimensional slice values using a single line command?

Tags: go, slice

Given the follow code:

```
    arr := [][]string {
        {"foo", "value1"},
        {"bar", "value2"},
        {"poo", "value3"},
    }
    fmt.Println(arr)
```

Is there a one liner of getting "value1", "value2" and "value3"?

I was thinking of:

```
    fmt.Println(arr[0:])
```

Was hoping maybe there is an option to do this:

```
    fmt.Println(arr[0:[1]])
```

Is there a way to do this without a foreach loop and appending items to a newly created slice?

Comment: This makes sense. I thought there is some magic Go functionality that I'm not aware of.

Comment: There's little reason to look for "one liners", newline characters are not a limited resource in need of preservation. Go favors readability over brevity.

Comment: I agree with @JimB. Even if a one liner existed, in many cases its bad practice, as it often results in pointless iterations instead of breaking or returning early

Answer (score 0):

To print the array values alone without a foreach loop ,you have to use the index value of values.I created simple program for the same scenario as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    

    arr := [][]string{
        {"foo", "value1"},
        {"bar", "value2"},
        {"poo", "value3"},
    }
    fmt.Println(arr[0][1],arr[1][1],arr[2][1])
    
}
```

Output:

```
value1 value2 value3
```

Comment: Thanks @Gopher, but unfortunately this doesn't scale when you have a longer array.

Answer (score 0):

If for loops are too mainstream for you, Go also has support for `goto` D: